# MS Access - query that sums a sum through multiple joined tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have three tables `Models`, `Buildups`, and `Components` with many-to-many join tables in between them. Each model can have multiple buildups and buildups are composed of multiple components. The components table has a field called `Retail`.

I'm trying to create a query for a report where the user can see a model and know the total buildup retail amount which would be the sum of the `Retail` field of each component in the buildup and then a sum of each buildup in the model.

I need a way to reference the Sum of the Sum of components without the enter parameter box appearing when the query is run (strange enough, when the parameter box is left blank it calculates correctly but I don't want the box to pop up).

Is the solution a nested query? If so, how would I do that? Or is the solution to use `DSum()`? Once again, if so, how would I implement that?

I'm not sure what to reference to make the criteria portion of the `DSum()` formula work correctly.

Comment: *I've created the first query* ... please post such attempted code on this programming Q/A site. Also, post the desired results. Natural languages like English tend to be imprecise compared to actual data.

Comment: I'll edit the post to remove that since the answer I was looking for is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your database structure or what you are looking to obtain, it seems like this would be sufficient:

```
select 
    mo.JandelModelID,
    sum(co.retail) as Total_Retail
from
    (   
        (
            tblJandelModels mo inner join tblJandelModelBuildups mb on
            mo.JandelModelID = mb.JandelModelID
        ) 
        inner join tblBuildupComponents bc on mb.BuildupID = bc.BuildupID
    )
    inner join tblComponents co on bc.ComponentID = co.ComponentID
group by
    mo.JandelModelID
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works great and I think I understand enough to add any other calculated fields from there!